# Erro ao executar Add-Migration Setup

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Ao executar o comando *Add-Migration Setup* para a criação da tabela no SQL Server no PM a mensagem abaixo ocorre mesmo eu fazendo a referência do projeto de api com o shared. O sistema até chega processar algo, mas logo dá esse error.

> No DbContext was found in assembly 'YouLearn.Api'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

Segue o link do repositório da [solução](https://github.com/cjuniorr/ddd-net-core)

Comment: Olá Célio, é recomendado deixar as mensagens de erro em forma de texto na sua pergunta e não imagem.

Comment: @DavidAlves Corrigido, obrigado.

Comment: Você definiu seu contexto no projeto que está tentando executar o comando? Olha o meu de exemplo: `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFContexto" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=AgilManager;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Agil.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: Minha resposta ajudou?

Comment: Oi Renan. Sua resposta me ajudou sim. Após seguir sua sugestão ainda encontrei mais um erro correspondendo a falta de um construtor não criado. Deu tudo certo, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Como sua classe de contexto do EF (`YouLearnContext`) está em ddd-net-core/*YouLearn.Infra*/Persistence/EF/, então ao executar o comando `Add-Migration Setup` você tem que selecionar o projeto *YouLearn.Infra*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]